# Why <String, String> entry allowed for HashMap<Integer, String>()?

Tags: java

I have `HashMap` which generic type `<Integer, String>` i.e. key should be an `Integer` and value should be `String` for this HashMap. 
I wrote bellow code which put `String` and getting no compilation and runtime error. Why?

```
Map map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put("a", "one");
System.out.println(map);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
{a=one}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have HashMap which generic type <Integer, String> ...

No you do not!

```
Map map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Means you have just a `Map` (because of `Map map =`). If you want `Map<Integer, String>` you must use:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

or, in later versions of Java

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

### Added

The reason for this is that the right-hand-side of the assignment is a **separate** process and is evaluated first. In your case it creates a `HashMap<Integer, String>`.

Next the assignment happens, the compiler checks that `HashMap<Integer, String>` can be cast to `Map` (which is equivalent to `Map<Object,Object>` BTW) and the assignment is performed. From then on **all** references to `map` treat it as type `Map<Object,Object>` and can therefore hold **any** type for key or value.

Comment: then what is the worth of ``<Integer, String>`` in HashMap<Integer, String> ?

Comment: @muzahidbechara - The right-hand-side item must only be `assignable` to the left-hand-side, it does not need to actually be that type, like `Object o = "Hello";`. It is the type of the **variable** that is used for type checking, not the type of the object assigned to that variable.

Comment: Role of ``<Integer, String>`` in HashMap<Integer, String> is only in the time assignment of map not during put/get ? Am I right

Answer (score 2):

You are adding content to `Map map` declared without specifying any generics types.

If you declare the map this way the compilator doesn't know how to check the map content.

If you change your map declaration to

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Then you will have a compilation error.

Comment: ``<Integer, String>`` of HashMap<Integer, String> is only check during assignment? not during put/get entry?

Comment: It's not a question of when it's checked, It about what to check. If you declare `Map map = ...` then your map can accept any kind of object. The , optionals, generics types on the right hand side of the declaration are not used to check the content of the map.

Comment: thanks ... so far I understand 
 
Role of ``<Integer, String>`` in HashMap<Integer, String> is only in the time assignment

Answer (score 1):

```
Map map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

Here your definition is type specified, however declaration is not. So, you are able to add any type to `map`.

The proper way for generic map declaration is

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

or in new versions of Java, you can skip type in defintion.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: then what is the worth of ``<Integer, String>`` in  HashMap<Integer, String> ?

Comment: I think it does n't make much difference. That is why it is optional in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Defining generics on the right side is more or less obsolete (grey font).

Following code wouldn't compile:

```
    Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("a", "one");
    System.out.println(map);
```

with this explanation:

> Wrong 1st argument type. Found: 'java.lang.String', required: 'java.lang.Integer'